# Why is Kotlin ignoring the delay(timeMillis: Long) function

Tags: kotlin, concurrency, kotlin-coroutines

#### The context

Following the Kotlin Coroutines basics guide at [this point](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/coroutines/basics.html#coroutines-are-light-weight)

using this code

```
fun coroutinesAreLightWeight()
{
    runBlocking {
        repeat(100_000) {
            launch {
                delay(1000L)
                print("$it, ")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

#### Issue

When I run the program on my computer it prints out all the digits in one go instead of waiting for 1 second to elapse before printing the next digit. This behaviour is the same when running the exact code as seen in the kotlin guide. It seems like the `delay()` function is being ignored

At first this block of code worked fine but then it stopped working as intended. I am using IntelliJ 2019.2.1 with kotlin version 1.3.50 and I have tried restarting the program but that didn't solve my problem.

Here is how the whole class looks like

```
class CoroutinesBasics
{
    fun ...

    fun ...

    fun coroutinesAreLightWeight()
    {
        runBlocking {
            repeat(100_000) {
                launch {
                    delay(1000L)
                    print("$it, ")
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

and the `coroutinesAreLightWeight()` function is called like this

```
fun main()
{
    CoroutineBasics().apply{
        ....
        ....
        coroutinesAreLightWeight()
    }
}
```

Can anyone point me to what is going on? Is this a Kotlin bug?

#### Kotlin dependencies

`implementation 'org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-core:1.3.0'`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'll take another angle to answer this.
The example is given in a specific context. Namely, "coroutines are not like threads". The goal of the example is not to demonstrate how to print numbers with delays, but to demonstrate that coroutines, unlike threads, can be launched in thousands simultaneously. And that's exactly what this code is doing. It submits them all, then executes them all.

You may ask then, why they are all sequential? Shouldn't they run concurrently?
For that, let's print the thread name:

```
repeat(100_000) {
    launch {
       delay(100L)
       println("$it, ${Thread.currentThread().name}")
    }
}
```

You'll quickly see the reason: `99999, main`

Since you're using `runBlocking`, all your coroutines are executed by a single thread.

We can change it, though:

```
runBlocking {
    repeat(100_000) {
        launch(Dispatchers.Default) {
            delay(100L)
            println("$it, ${Thread.currentThread().name}")
        }
    }
}
```

By using `Dispatchers.Default`, we're running our coroutines on a default thread pool. And then the results become much less predictable:

```
98483, DefaultDispatcher-worker-6
99898, DefaultDispatcher-worker-5
99855, DefaultDispatcher-worker-1
99706, DefaultDispatcher-worker-2
```

The default thread pool starts with 2 threads, and goes up to number of CPU cores by default. You can look at `createDefaultDispatcher()` for the actual implementation.

Regarding `Thread.sleep()`, you should know a few things:

1. Never use `Thread.sleep()` inside coroutine
2. Never use `Thread.sleep()` inside coroutine
3. IntelliJ will even warn you to never use `Thread.sleep()` inside coroutine

Let's look at the following example to understand why:

```
repeat(100_000) {
   launch {
      Thread.sleep(100) 
      println("$it, ${Thread.currentThread().name}")
   }
}
```

You may assume what you're saying is "don't do anything in this block for 100ms".

But what you're actually saying is "don't do literally anything for 100ms".

Since `launch` will execute on context it got from `runBlocking`, and `runBlocking` is a single threaded context, you block executions of all coroutines.

Comment: I now understand, your explanation was clear and concise.

Am I correct to say that the threads in the default thread pool are spawned as they are needed? Is there a limit to the number of tasks that can be run on one thread?

Comment: When using `Thread.sleep()` inside the `launch` is Kotlin registering all 100,000 launched coroutines at once and then executing them one by one?

Comment: The answer is somewhat complicated, so I'll update my initial answer, instead of answering you in the comments.

Answer (score 0):

This is the intended behavior as far as I know because coroutines are working simultaneously, so your code will only wait for 1 second for all coroutines that are currently working.

A good talk that I recommend about the coroutines is:
[KotlinConf 2017 - Introduction to Coroutines by Roman Elizarov](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_hfBv0a09Jc)

And it has the exact same example in the slides :)

if you want them to wait you should move the repeat to outside the 'runBlocking'

Comment: But according to the Kotlin Coroutines guide it reads 

"It launches 100K coroutines and, after a second, each coroutine prints a dot."

Comment: Can you try to print something just before `runBlocking {
        repeat(100_000) {`

Comment: Or just increase the delay for 10 seconds so you can tell if it is waiting or not

Comment: The print works as expected if put before `runBlocking`

Comment: It waits. But still the actual result varies from what is written in the guide. The launched coroutine is supposed to run the delay first before printing a line and then repeat the process up to the number of times specified in the `repeat` function

Comment: what will happen with your code is: it will create 100000 coroutines for you, every one of them will wait for 1 second then print. so you will have 100000 prints after exactly one second. because all code inside that block will work concurrently

Comment: Replacing `delay(`) with `Thread.sleep()` works as I expect it to. It prints a new digit after every second, it doesn't work that way with `delay()`

Comment: Because `delay` and `Thread.sleep` are totally different functions. `Thread.sleep` is a blocking call that will block the coroutines, and every time you call `sleep` it will block the thread and the other coroutines will not have any chance to run unless the thread is released. `delay` will not block your execution  it will delay the coroutine itself